# Create a static instance of the same class

Tags: python, python-3.11

I'd like to create a static instance of a class. Assume I have the following data class:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class MyTag:
    tag: str
```

(i.e. a class with a string member called tag).

Now I want to create a specific version of this tag (the `GLOBAL` value, with tag `'<<GLOBAL>>'` to be stored as a class member, and I want it to be a class member so that I can call `MyTag.GLOBAL`.

What I came up with is this code:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class MyTag:
    tag: str

    GLOBAL = None
    '''The global value'''

MyTag.GLOBAL = MyTag(tag='<<GLOBAL>>')
```

Now, this seems a bit ugly to me, so I'm wondering whether there is a prettier way to do this.

I first went with this syntax:

```py
[...]
    GLOBAL = MyTag(tag='<<GLOBAL>>')
    '''The global value'''
```

But even with `from __future__ import annotations` at the beginning it complained because `MyTag` was not defined.

I'm using Python 3.11 at present, if the answer is influenced by the version

Comment: Can you use an Enum with a single member?

Comment: There's probably a better duplicate for this, but the short version is that you can't define the instance within its own class, because Python is running the code inside the `class` body in order to figure out the class definition, and at the time it's doing that, the name hasn't been assigned yet (it can't be, because the class doesn't exist yet, because Python is still busy figuring out the definition).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel thank you; that definitely makes sense. I think I'll stick with my solution then, so to define the value after the class definition